# PdfDocument on Android - filling a PDF with

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

to my understanding for creating Pdfs on Android starting version 4.4 I can use the PdfDocument class, which generally works like this:

```
        PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(textView.getWidth(), textView.getHeight(), 1).create();
        Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        View content = textview;
        content.draw(page.getCanvas());
        document.finishPage(page);
```

So basically I am taking my layout, draw it on the canvas, and PdfDocument creates a PDF out of it. 
This is working, I would like to know however if it is possible to simply add text as string, for example, without using TextViews etc., and create a PDF out of that?

Answer (score 2):

> if it is possible to simply add text as string, for example, without using TextViews etc., and create a PDF out of that?

Not using the Android SDK options. You can create a PDF out of Web content (via `WebView`), a `Canvas` (whether using views or the native `Canvas` drawing API), or a `Bitmap`. There are third-party PDF libraries (e.g., iText) for other PDF-generation scenarios.